# Suppressing printing epoch in PyGad

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, genetic-algorithm

I'm using Pygad to train a Keras NN through genetic algorithm, and as far as I can tell the code works, however, I do not know how to prevent it from printing the epoch in the terminal:

```
ga_instance = pygad.GA(num_generations=15, num_parents_mating=5, fitness_func=fitness_func, 
initial_population=keras_ga.population_weights, on_generation=on_generation, suppress_warnings=True)
```

As you can see here, I've already set `suppress_warnings=True`, however, when I run `ga_instance.run()`, the terminal will continue to print these texts:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 37ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 38ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 33ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step
```

I'm not sure if this issue is being caused by PyGad or Tensorflow, but I couldn't figured out a way to solve this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `fitness` and `on_generation` functions, if you use any print statements and remove them.

Otherwise, the `PyGad` doesn't print output with itself unless there are warnings or errors.

And you already prevented the suppress warnings

`suppress_warnings`: A bool parameter to control whether the warning messages are printed or not. It defaults to False. check the documentation for more information about the parameters: https://pygad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README_pygad_ReadTheDocs.html

Comment: Thank you, I've went back and checked each line, and it turns out `model.predict()` was inside the fitness function was printing it, passing the parameter `verbose=0` fixed it.

Comment: You are welcome, glad to hear it is working :)

Answer (score 4):

An addition for others running into this:
As already realized this output is generated by the `model.predict()` function of keras probably used in your fitness function. Setting `verbose=0` disables it but is not optimal because `predict()` is optimized for batch processing of inputs not currently supported by PyGad.
For repeatedly predicting on small batches of data use the `__call__()` of the model e.g. `model(solution)` instead of `model.predict(solution)`.

See: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict